# List authors that have written certain number of posts in category/tags in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm struggling to get the list of authors on the category page. I need to list the authors who have written at least 5 articles in that category.

I need something like this in tags also.

Any idea how to do this in wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
function list_author_in_this_cat ($with) {
if (is_category()) {
    $current_category = get_query_var('cat');
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'category' => $current_category,
        'orderby' => 'author',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
} else {
    $tag_id = get_query_var('tag_id');
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'tag__in' =>  $tag_id,
        'orderby' => 'author',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
}
$cat_posts = get_posts($args);

$author_id_array = array();
$user_posts = array();
foreach( $cat_posts as $cat_post ):
    $user_posts[$cat_post->post_author][] = $cat_post->ID;
endforeach;

foreach( $user_posts as $key => $user_post ):   
    $user_post = array_unique($user_post);
    $count_user_posts[$key] = count($user_post);

    if ($count_user_posts[$key] >= $with) {
        $author_id_array[] = $key;
    }       
endforeach;

return $author_id_array; }
```

In your theme files, place this code wherever you want the list of authors to be displayed:

```
if (is_category() || is_tag()) {

    $at_least = 5;  // at least 5 articles in current category or tags

    $author_array = list_author_in_this_cat ($at_least);
    foreach (array_slice($author_array, 0, 4) as $author) : // limit 4 results
        $name = get_userdata($author)->display_name;
        $link = get_userdata($author)->user_login;
        echo "<a href='/author/".$link."'>".$name."</a>\n";
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: hi this works correctly... thanks. I need to display only 4 authors if there are more than 4 authors in results. Thank you once again.

Comment: Use `array_slice()` function to limit the number of authors. I've edit my code.

Answer (score 7):

Its only possible with a custom SQL query so here is a simple function which should return an array with user id's of users with at least $n posts in the current term archive, which means it should work in categories, tags and custom taxonomies

```
function get_authors_with($num = 5){
    global $wpdb;
    $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
    $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
    $sub_q = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
            INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
            INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
            WHERE ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = %s
            AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = '%s'
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish')",
        $current_term->term_id,
        $taxonomyName
    );
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT $wpdb->posts.post_author, FROM (%s)
            GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.post_author
            HAVING count(*) > %s",
            $sub_q,
            $num
    );
    return $wpdb->get_results($sql);
}
```

Comment: Just one correction - you can get the current term by doing `get_queried_object()`, instead of doing `get_term_by()` - basically the `WP_Query` object will do the same thing for you, with the exception that if someone has already accessed the queried object, you will get it from "cache" instead of doing a new term query.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your theme's function.php

```
function get_authors_in_category ( $category_id, $min_posts ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => 1000, 'category' => $category_id ) );
    $author_count = array();
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if( array_key_exists( get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author ), $author_count ) ) {
      $author_count[get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author )]++;
     } else { $author_count[get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author )] = 1; }
    }
    $authors = array();
    foreach ( $author_count as $author_name => $count ) {
    if ( $min_posts  <= $count ) {
    $authors[] = $author_name;
    }
    return $authors;
  }
```

This function as you can see returns an array of authors who have a minimum number of posts in a category. Category ID has to be passed, this can be obtained using the wordpress function get_cat_ID.

You can call this function from any where in the theme and display the authors as you wish.

Note: This is a more resource intensive than the custom SQL functions. Also this function might have some errors, I typed it here and didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

I did some simple coding with query post method.,

```
<?php 
$cur_cat_id = get_cat_id(single_cat_title("",false));
$posts=query_posts("cat=$cur_cat_id&order=ASC");
foreach($posts as $post){
$number_of_posts = number_format_i18n(get_the_author_posts($post->post_author));
if($number_of_posts>5)
{
echo the_author_meta('user_nicename',$post->post_author)."(".number_format_i18n(get_the_author_posts($post->post_author)).")<br>";
}
}
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: It prints an author more than one time